# Twitter bot using Oauth

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have a twitter bot, where it searches for an @mention and replies to the user depending on what the user says.

It was working fine until this week, when I started getting this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/reportax/public_html/reportaxi/twitterbot/config.php on line 14

I stripped down the code to the most basic form, which is the searching for the @mention and then tweeting something when it finds it, but I'm still getting this error. Any ideas?

As I mentioned before, this was working fine until this week, so I know the consumer key, secret, and all that is OK.

here's the code:

```
<?php
require_once('twitteroauth.php');

define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'MYKEY');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'MYSECRET');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', 'MYTOKEN');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', 'MYTOKENSECRET');

$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
$twitter->host = "http://search.twitter.com/";
$search = $twitter->get('search', array('q' => '@repor_taxi', 'rpp' => 15));

$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1/";
foreach($search->results as $tweet) {
    $status = 'RT @'.$tweet->from_user.' '.$tweet->text;
    if(strlen($status) > 140) $status = substr($status, 0, 139);
    $twitter->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $status));
}

?
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need update your code for twitter API 1.1.

```
<?php
require_once('twitteroauth.php');

define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'MYKEY');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'MYSECRET');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', 'MYTOKEN');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', 'MYTOKENSECRET');

$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

/*The search has change a little bit */

/* Remove this 2 lines */
/* $twitter->host = "http://search.twitter.com/"; */
/* $search = $twitter->get('search', array('q' => '@repor_taxi', 'rpp' => 15)); */

/* Put this new line */
$search = $twitter->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=@repor_taxi&count=15");

/* The Search URL is https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q= */
/* Everything after is parameter */
/* You can check parameters list here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search */

/* Twitter host updated too */
$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";

foreach($search as $tweet) {
    ...     
?>
```

I hope this may help you. Good luck.